# POST values with silex (form submission)

Tags: php, forms, post, silex

I'm new to Silex and I'm really messed up with it.
I'm trying to do a simple login form and I don't know how to properly handle the POST submissions of my form.

I know I have to set something up in my Silex index, but I don't know how to do it. Basically, what I want is to be able to do something with the post values of the form. This is my actual code:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/protected/vendor/autoload.php';

use Herrera\Template\TemplateServiceProvider;
use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;
use Phinx\Db\Adapter;


$parser = new Parser();
$config = $parser->parse(file_get_contents(__DIR__ .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'protected'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'main.yml'));

$app = new Application();

$app->register(new TemplateServiceProvider(), array('template.dir' => __DIR__ . '/protected/views/'));

/** @var Herrera\Template\Engine $engine */
$engine = $app['template.engine'];

$app->get('/admin', function() use($engine, $config) {
    return $engine->render('admin.php', array(
        'static_url' => $config['static_url'],
        'title'  => 'Admin'
    ), true);
});

$app->run();
?>
```

And well, my admin.php file, where the form is, is a simple html form.
I've been searching for answers for this, but I haven't found anything I could understand/do...

Hope you can help me!
Thanks!

Comment: and where is the login form posted to? How do you handle that path? You should add it in your router or add the code if already exists

Comment: @NikosM. Well, what I simply want is to send this post values to somewhere where I can send it to the db, like I would do with a normal form with raw php. Is it possible to send them to the same file (admin.php) where the form is?? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't sent the data to the same file as you should have a clear separation of code. Your form is part of your view, but the handling of the form should be done in a controller (being a clousure, a function or a method in a class). I think you may want to take a look at the fantastic series from Fabien Potencier (the creator of Symfony and coauthor of Silex) about [Creating your own framework on top of the Symfony2 Components](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1)

Answer (score 2):

You should create a `POST` route that will be used after your form is submitted. Then access form values in `Request` object. For example:

```
$app->post('/admin', function (Request $request) {
    $login = $request->get('login');
    $password = $request->get('password');

    // Further processing
});
```

Have look at docs: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#example-post-route

Comment: Okay, thanks! I used this to call my UserDAO class and add a user to the database: http://pastebin.com/Z8MbTvt2, but it doesn't work... It's something I'm using wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your form is submitted using the correct URL. Simple solution, as post and get routes in your code use the same path: make the action attribute of the form empty, like `action=""`.

Comment: I've checked my form action tag, and it's empty. Simply, when I submit the form, a blank page is displayed... Do you want me to post you any other of my files? Thanks!

Comment: All right, I've changed something in my User class and now it works perfectly with the database, but when the form is submitted and the code after the form is run, it shows me a 500 error code. Although, the code (the user registration) is ran successfully because I can see my addition in the database. Do I have to ignore this 500 error code and simply redirect somewhere after the form? Also, if I have to do it, how can I do it? Simply with a header(Location)? Thanks!

Comment: All right... Sorry for the three comments... But I found the redirect ($app->redirect()), but the 500 error code is there... What I'm only doing is kinda hiding it with a redirect. Is this bad? Thanks!